# Getting Nullpointer exception when UnitTesting Android TabActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, tabactivity, activityunittestcase

I am currently unittesting the sample TabLayout from [android website](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). I am getting a NullPointerException when unittesting it like this:

```
public class MainActivityUnitTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity>{

    public MainActivityUnitTest(){
        super(MainActivity.class);      
    }

    @MediumTest
    public void testStartActivity(){
        setActivity(startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN), null, null));
    }
}
```

This is the exception that I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:277)
at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
at com.foo.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:159)
at com.foo.android.test.MainActivityUnitTest.testStartActivity(MainActivityUnitTest.java:17)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

I tried to search the net with no luck. I am hoping somebody has resolved an issue like this before. What have I done wrong here? Thank you very much in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Did eu get to solve this issue?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with unit testing so I can't say for sure, but it looks like you didn't set the class and context for the `startActivity intent`.

Comment: I don't think so. It works with normal Activity. It just fails with TabActivity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ActivityUnitTestCase prevents execution of startActivity() to provide isolated environment to test target activity as described in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html). When TabWidget invokes addTab() it calls startActivity() to start activity that will fill the tabcontent but startActivity() does nothing, so addTab() fails with NullPointerException.

I can't find any way to avoid this problem. I just switch it to ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 then test goes fine. But, in this case, I can't use mock context to test other things. Also, it runs activity under actual system (I can see the activity on the screen) very slowly (Just a simple test takes 1 sec on my device). So if you don’t need to mock context, using ActivityInstumentationTestCase2 can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *ActivityUnitTestCase* because it make a test only on "the unit" actionbar isn't in the unit if you want to test it you must extend **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2** and check what say mathume

Answer (score -1):

If `getActionBar()` can return `null`, check for it:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && ab != null) {
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

This solved the issue for me.