# Test that an Activity Started a Service

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-service, android-testing

How do I test that my activity started a service with a particular intent?

My question is similar to [Unit testing Activity.startService() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294211/unit-testing-activity-startservice-call), but I ran into an [action bar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236977/getting-nullpointer-exception-when-unittesting-android-tabactivity#answer-9866572) when I used ActivityUnitTestCase.

Here is an example of what I would like to test:

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testAddSongToAvailableList() {
    ListView songList = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.allSongsList);
    songList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.btnAddToAvailableList).performClick(); // should start my service

    //assert that my service was started and is doing stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass in the data as a bundle to the initiating activity?

Are you simple testing the service is started or do you want to specifically know which activity initiated the service?

Comment: Ideally I want to test that the service received the activity's intent. Something like an ActivityMonitor would work nicely, but I don't know of one for services.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a service using startService method, you can determine if the activity has started or not by return value of the method.

If service started successfully, it returns `the ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else if the service does not exist null is returned.`

For more detail: [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: I am unit testing my application. Basically I am testing that that `startService()` was called.